# sed filtering of tshark dump: speedup

Tags: regex, optimization, sed

I'm filtering output generated by tshark with sed to only show Info and Bytes of packages. But when the tshark output gets too long, this can be too slow in some instances. I have not much experience with sed: Is there any way to speed this up? I think at the moment I run sed 5 times on each line with different expressions, but I remember researching this and find out that there is no "or" in my sed version. Would awk be faster?

```
tshark -P -x -r btdebug.snoop | sed -n 's/^.*\(Reassembled.*\)$/\1/p;s/^.*\(Sent.*\)$/\1/p;s/^.*\(Rcvd.*\)$/\1/p;s/^.*\(PT=.*\)$/\1/p;s/^[0-9a-f]*\s\(\(\s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)\{1,16\}\).*$/\1/p'
```

EDIT: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qzXkV9F9rjGmlvDo7CoxwjXZVRbQWDe- with example outputs from just tshark and after sed.

Comment: added links for tsharkout.txt and expecetedsedout.txt

Comment: Have you considered dumping only the data you care about, instead of trying to filter after-the-fact?

Comment: See `tshark -G` to list the available format-string operators you can use in format streams when telling tshark what output format you want it to generate.

Comment: You're correct I can let tshark output only the Info by adding -o 'gui.column.format:"Info","%i"'. But I think I cannot change the behaviour how the bytes are printed, so it would still require me to filter with sed.

Comment: you can create `OR` regular expressions by using call `sed -E` and having regexs like `/this|or that/`, the `|` char being the `OR` operator) but they can be tricky to test so allow extra time AND it may or may not improve the speed. Good luck.

Comment: I am finding sed faster than `grep -o` for this, especially when writing to a file.  Writing to a file is an order of magnitude faster than writing to stdout.